# Register form field

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, register

i use magento 1.9.x, need in form register add next field: Username,
Password, Confirm Password, Location, First Name, Last Name, Phone, how i can do this? i need also store in backend this filed in customer account admin, how in possible? can you help me solove this problem?

Comment: After complete code clear cache but registration form missing just showing License Number field.[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEXPj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEXPj.png) It's need immediate, please help now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base you need on this solution and customise it according to the fields that you want to add.

We will create a new extension to make it clean.

Let's call the extension `StackExchange_Customer`.
You will need the following files:

```
1- app/etc/modules/StackExchange_Customer.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Customer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends><Mage_Customer/></depends>
        </StackExchange_Customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

```
2- app/code/local/StackExchange/Customer/etc/config.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Customer>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackExchange_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <stackexchange_customer>
                <class>StackExchange_Customer_Helper</class>
            </stackexchange_customer>
        </helpers>
        <resources>
            <stackexchange_customer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>StackExchange_Customer</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </stackexchange_customer_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <stackexchange_customer>
                    <file>stackexchange_customer.xml</file>
                </stackexchange_customer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <StackExchange_Customer>
                    <files>
                        <default>StackExchange_Customer.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </StackExchange_Customer>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

```
3- app/code/local/StackExchange/Customer/sql/stackexchange_customer_setup/install-1.0.0.php
```

```
<?php
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'license_number', array(
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'label'     => 'License Number',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'position'  => 120,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'license_number');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();
```

```
4- app/code/local/StackExchange/Customer/Helper/Data.php
```

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Customer_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

> This will add your attribute for the customer in admin, and now we have to edit the frontend templates to add the field to the customer.

```
5- app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/stackexchange_customer.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <customer_account_edit>
        <reference name="customer_edit">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>stackexchange_customer/form/edit.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_edit>
    <customer_account_create>
        <reference name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>stackexchange_customer/register.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>
</layout>
```

```
6- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/stackexchange_customer/register.phtml
```

For this one make a clone of the /app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml and just insert this somewhere inside the form. I don't need to post the full file here. Arrange it as you please

```
<li>
    <label for="license_number"><?php echo $this->__('License Number') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="license_number" id="license_number" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getLicenseNumber()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('License Number') ?>" class="input-text" />
    </div>
</li>
```

```
7- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/stackexchange_customer/form/edit.phtml
```

For this one clone /app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/form/edit.phtml and insert somewhere inside the form this:

```
<li>
    <label for="license_number"><?php echo $this->__('License Number') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="license_number" id="license_number" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCustomer()->getLicenseNumber()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('License Number') ?>" class="input-text" />
    </div>
</li>
```

```
8- app/locale/en_US/StackExchange_Customer.csv
```

```
"License Number","License Number"
```

Clear the cache and enjoy