# Add new Mobile Number field in magento(1.9) customer registration form

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer-account, forms

I want to add Mobile number field to customer registration form. So that user can login with help of email id or mobile number.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custome-account-profile-13594.html

I have tried this extension but it shows me an error.

I have tried creating simple custom extension "Hello World" but don't have experience to write any useful extension .

Can you please give some idea related to my requirement?

Comment: Good one https://magecomp.com/magento-mobile-login.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You have to create the attribute `phone_number` and then display it for the customer in `register.phtml` and `edit.phtml`, you have to follow this [tuto](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/168048/48355)

2- You have to Rewritte `loginPostAction()` from `AccountController.php` to your local codepool, you can follow this [tuto](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/92173/48355) and then you add this piece of code in `loginPostAction()`:

```
if (strpos($login['username'], '@') === false){ //the user has entred a phone number
          $telUser = $login['username'];
          $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('phone_number', $telUser)
                       ->getFirstItem();
          if($telUser == $customer->getPhoneNumber()){
              $login['username'] = $customer->getEmail();
          }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have follow  the step 1 steps but unable to find whether the mobile number is store in db or not, how can i check for that?

Comment: Have you a phone_number field in customer tab in backoffice ?

Comment: sorry i don't get your point, i have just follow same step mention there in first link

Comment: I dont know what this extension have like code !, however if you dont have your custom field phone_number(see how you named it),  it's that it doesn't work. I suggest you to follow my answer for step 1 and then  step 2.