# Magento problem in extension

Tags: magento-1.9, php, register

i have tried to develop custom extension for adding new field in register customer field using below link

[Register form field](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168024/register-form-field/168048#168048)

**app\etc\modules\Imorse_Mobile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Imorse_Mobile>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends><Mage_Customer/></depends>
        </Imorse_Mobile>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app\code\local\Imorse\Mobile\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Imorse_Mobile>
             <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Imorse_Mobile>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Imorse_Mobile>
                 <class>Imorse_Mobile_Helper</class>
            </Imorse_Mobile>
        </helpers>

        <resources>
            <Imorse_Mobile_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Imorse_Mobile</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </Imorse_Mobile_setup>
        </resources>

    </global>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>   
                <Imorse_Mobile>
                    <file>Imorse_Mobile.xml</file>
                </Imorse_Mobile>
            </updates>  
        </layout>
         <translate>
            <modules>
                <Imorse_Mobile>
                    <files>
                         <default>Imorse_Mobile.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Imorse_Mobile>
            </modules>
         </translate>
        <routers>
            <!-- <routeName> -->
                <customer>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <Imorse_Mobile before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">Imorse_Mobile</Imorse_Mobile>
                        </modules>

                    </args>
                </customer>
            <!-- </routeName> -->
         </routers> 
    </frontend>

</config>
```

**app\code\local\Imorse\Mobile\sql\Imorse_Mobile_setup\install-1.0.0.php**

```
<?php
    $this->addAttribute('customer','mobile_number',array(
         'type'      => 'varchar',
        'label'     => 'Mobile Number',
        'input'     => 'text',
        'position'  => 120,
        'required'  => true,//or true
        'is_system' => 0,
    ));
    $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'mobile_number');

    $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
        'adminhtml_customer',
        'checkout_register',
        'customer_account_create',
        'customer_account_edit',
    ));
    $attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
    $attribute->save();


?>
```

But it is unable to store mobile number in db

Also try to extend controller
**app\code\local\Imorse\Mobile\controllers\AccountController.php**

```
<?php 
    require 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';

    class Imorse_Mobile_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{

        public function loginPostAction(){
            die("yes");
        }
    }
?>
```

But it always find the action in core controller,
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think file name is wrong.

Change

```
app\code\local\Imorse\Mobile\etc\congix.xml
```

to

```
app\code\local\Imorse\Mobile\etc\config.xml
```

And update router xml code as follows

```
<routers>
    <customer>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <Imorse_Mobile before="Mage_Customer">Imorse_Mobile</Imorse_Mobile>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </customer>
</routers>
```

Comment: thank youfor reply, the name of actual file is current. i have put it here wrong by mistake

Comment: Okay. I updated answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Update router code to this

```
<routers>
    <customer>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <Imorse_Mobile before="Mage_Customer">Imorse_Mobile</Imorse_Mobile>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </customer>
</routers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code to solve your issue.

**app/etc/modules/Imorse_Mobile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Imorse_Mobile>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Imorse_Mobile>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Imorse/Mobile/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Imorse_Mobile>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Imorse_Mobile>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <mobile>
        <class>Imorse_Mobile_Helper</class>
      </mobile>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <mobile>
        <class>Imorse_Mobile_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>mobile_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </mobile>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Imorse_Mobile</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute_setup>
      <customerattribute_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute_write>
      <customerattribute_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Imorse/Mobile/Helper/Data.php**

```
class Imorse_Mobile_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

**app/code/local/Imorse/Mobile/sql/customerattribute_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("customer", "mobile_number",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Mobile Number",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => true,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

    ));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "mobile_number");


$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
        ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
        ->setData("is_system", 0)
        ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
        ->setData("is_visible", 1)
        ->setData("sort_order", 100);
$attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

**N.B : No need to override customer controller its a customer attribute.**